# 2D physics with colliding circles but one is always fixed to its position

Tags: geometry, 2d, processing, physics, collision

I am programming a 2D game in Processing, and I want to have a circle that is always stationary (whether or not something is pushing against it), and another circle moving towards the stationary one at any angle. After collision, the moving circle should bounce off the stationary one.

How would I make a general statement to tell the computer where the moving circle's velocity will point right after collision?

Answer (score 2):

If one of the objects is stationary and the collision is elastic (the typical thing people want to show), then the ball bounces just as though it was bouncing off the tangent line at the point of contact.

That is: 1) find the point of contact of the circles at the time of collision. 2) Determine the radial line to this point.  3) The bounce angle will then be such that the radial line bisects the angle between the incident direction and departure direction.